# How to enable blazor united on a blazor wasm project?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48G_CEGXZZM) there is a feature called Blazor United.
Blazor United is a prototype project from Steve Sanderson, the original creator of Blazor, which combines the advantages of Razor Pages, Blazor Server, and Blazor WebAssembly into a single stack. The prototype is currently in development and is expected to be included in .NET 8. Some of the features of the prototype include support for traditional server-side rendering, WebAssembly, and WebSockets. Additionally, the prototype includes features such as hot module reloading, lazy loading, and prerendering. The project is still in its early stages, and more features and improvements are expected to arrive in the future.

How to add this to a .net 7 blazor wasm project by this link :
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/blazor-united

Comment: I think you will create a new stack and add your existing code to it. Blazor Wasm can't be the  'platform' for the other tech.

Answer (score 1):

Blazor United will come as part of .NET8. So you will have to at least wait for second preview of .NET8 before you will be able to experiment with it. Till then, just wait.

Answer (score 1):

We have to wait for .net 8 preview 8 to be released.

Comment: Then how do you do it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Install **.net 8** and latest version of **Visual Studio 2022**.

Create a **blazor web app** template project. select **.net 8**, set interactivity mode to **Auto** and select Global if you want blazor united in all pages.

[image]

[image]